# Function as template argument for a field of a class that has THAT function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

It is easier to explain it in code.

**Example**

I have a hash-map data structure that has template as followed :-

```
template<class K,class T,long (* K_hashingFunction)(K&)> class AMap{
    //  ^ Key     ^Value       ^ Hashing function for Key
}
```

It works as I expected.

Then I want to declare an iterator class as followed:-

```
template<class K,class T,long (* K_hashingFunction)(K&)> class AMap_iterator{
    AMap<K,T, ????? >* mapPtr=nullptr; //How should I declare its type?
 }
```

**Question:** What is a correct way to declare **mapPtr** as a field?

```
AMap<K,T,  K_hashingFunction >* mapPtr=nullptr; //?
AMap<K,T, &K_hashingFunction >* mapPtr=nullptr; //?
AMap<K,T, *K_hashingFunction> * mapPtr=nullptr; //?
```

All theses give me an intellisense error :  "Cannot substitute template argument"

Comment: Intellisense errors are no errors (only hints of possible errors). `AMap<K,T,  K_hashingFunction >* mapPtr=nullptr;` is correct.

Comment: Yes, I accept  C++11 and higher.   and thank! Dieter Lücking.

Comment: Why not simply use `AMap*`?

Comment: I guess I have to, because I will access its function / field from iterator.  e.g. *iterator return K or T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:

```
AMap<K,T,  K_hashingFunction >* mapPtr=nullptr;
```

We're just copying all the template parameters - no modification necessary. Note that dereferencing the function pointer should also work since the function would just decay back to the pointer to.

Due to injected class names though, we can simplify to:

```
AMap* mapPtr = nullptr;
```

Comment: But this type is used inside `AMap_iterator`, so the injected class name method wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Barry's answer.

```
AMap<K,T, &K_hashingFunction >* mapPtr=nullptr;
```

Is incorrect because expression `&K_hashingFunction` would return *pointer to pointer to function*. Not *pointer to function*.